# Make an infinite chain

Tags: code-golf, math, number, open-ended-function

Lets define a class of functions.  These functions will map from the positive integers to the positive integers and must satisfy the following requirements:

- The function must be Bijective, meaning that every value maps to and is mapped to by exactly one value.
- You must be able to get from any positive integer to any other positive integer by repeated applications of the function or its inverse.

Now, write some code that will perform any one function in this class on its input.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Jack Sure, Consider the function that maps 1 -> 2, maps every other odd number to that number minus 2, and every even number to that number plus 2.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Would f(x) := x+1 be a function of this class? In that case, `1+` in common lisp should do the trick here.

Comment: Continuing from MONODA43's question, would something like f(x) := x be valid?

Comment: @MONODA43 That function is a bijection when considering all integers. But this question asks for a bijection on the positive integers. Your suggestion would fail to output 1 because there is no positive x for which x+1=1.

Comment: @Cowsquack **You must be able to get from any positive integer to any other positive integer by repeated applications of the function or its inverse.** You cannot get from 1 to 2 by applying the identity, no matter how many times you repeat.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to asking for a permutation of the integers with no finite cycle.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is not. Two separate chains covering all the positive integers would not have any finite cycles, but it wouldn't be possible to get between arbitrary pairs of integers of there were two separate chains.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In general take any valid answer generating a single chain. Now you can construct a pair of chains as follows. Multiply every number in the original chain by 2 to generate one chain. Multiply every number in the original chain by 2 and subtract one to generate another chain. The two chains generated this way would form a bijection on the positive integers, but would not be a valid answer.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:n-(-1)**n*2or 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxCoQwEAXQWk/xG3EmmCKxE/Qk20TcqKBfCdnC02dt3rufvF3sS8SITznCOS8BHGjFOjWGxl8JrsRXYidS4PoV18E7HerqTjuztI3/wU54a9FA2CEKVbX8AQ)

Comment: Ha, you ninja'd me because I took 20 extra seconds to write out my sequence before posting...

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 22 bytes

```py
lambda n:n+n%2*4-2or 1
```

The even numbers go down to the previous even number, odd numbers go up to the next odd number, and the mapping 2 -> 1 connects those two.

Comment: wait... so 6 can result from 5 or 8? that's invalid?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon No, just a replaced odd with even in my explanation.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 20 bytes

```
n=>n>1?n%2?n-2:n+2:2
```

Maps `... -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> ...`, which I *think* is valid. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Alike minds think great. I'm using the inverse.

Comment: @Dennis Heh, and I've just realized that the inverse is 1 byte shorter: `n=>n%2?n+2:n-2||1:2`

Comment: @Dennis You have been confirmed to be Yoda :o ([StepHen's chat post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38952636#38952636))

Comment: @HyperNeutrino *Greatly, alike minds think*

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```
f 1=2
f x=x+2*(-1)^x
```

The example function from the OP's comment in Haskell. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03B0NaIK02hwrZC20hLQ9dQM67if25iZp6CrUJKPpeCQkFRZl6JgopCmoIpCs8YhWeIwjNC4Zlw/QcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
-*Ḥạo1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//LSrhuKThuqFvMf8yMFLCtcW8w4figqxH/w)

#### How it works

```
-*Ḥạo1  Main link. Argument: n

-*      Compute (-1)**n, yielding 1 for even n and -1 for odd n.
  Ḥ     Unhalve; multipliy the result by 2.
   ạ    Compute the absolute difference of the result and n.
    o1  If the difference is 0, yield 1.
```

Comment: Are we really letting Dennis get away with 'unhalve'? Haha.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 43 bytes

```
lambda n,a=(1,3,-3,-1):n+a[n%4]if n-2else 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDsIgGEXhuT7FXUghwgB1alJfRB1@IyhJvSVYB58eSU5ylq/89tfGqSUsuLZV3veHgFYW7e1kXc@bmUe5UJ1uOYEuxPUT4VvaKohMVOEzdo7Q6WEoNXPXowpfuDP6RihoWiRNY0z7Aw)

And the inverse, also 43 bytes:

```
lambda n,a=(-3,-1,1,3):n+a[n%4]if n-1else 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcWxDsIgFAXQWb/iLqSP@BgApyb1R9QBIyhJvW2wDn49epazfrfnwtgLJlz6nF63ewI1TeKiOq9eox15SGea47UW0Pk8vzNCL0sDUYmW@MjiFcHbcb9bW@UmgwkfuBP@DTAQKorQWtt/)

TIO links use Dennis's test footer code.

Since everyone is using one way of doing, I decided I'd be different, so I created by own (although I'm probably not the first person to discover it) function. This functions maps like `... 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 5 -> 8 -> 9 -> ...`, I can show you the hand drawing I made to test this if you would like.

My golfed algorithm <s>may be</s> probably is golfable - tips would be appreciated.

Ungolfed versions: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9BCsMgEEXX9RR/E6I0gapdFexdCtXURSZBzKKntyZQGi2Frhx8n5n352d8TKRTulsHx0lcGLwDwRioPCPYuASCZBhh8n@D85YY18RplyAc19QbyQrpD1IF6vdIV0iy1Wsovfar1R9exQX5deGHV9FG122Sm0KePCHcaLBcdlAySx7m4CnytlEL@ivy02Y1Tt1WQoj0Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 10 bytes

```
48 83 F0 01 74 01 40 34 01 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwEDzjr9hSRbEDifKQekhCLjn30lOlpkKOMeDWGGSgdRrl10ttElS1Pqy9s@Od8ZpV1TRjrOvuhWKyTThs6yYR5SzfoT@QFMf/mBYqcxjipuFagb/34RzHtLGVY9vwOMZY86yiusALQggI1UCKXaRkc0G0LgDDk4/RLJPlkUpIUbpGXsIZcGqQZ0rtDiEskPf2BfW7qJBnDfRVl62vHCp7iuYNIj6QDUJOo6BCXcV0xkJgOdUwmdjkg6AzArtc0UAE8xBObtv06GcuJAccBAa2ESweSI@6VdkXNyn2RwKmOxiJg/JDsPZSbAi5Xh4oB/VIWS4UB1YmfO3fyuZXJinhPLBhNF8@216nCONW1SJTPOkNT0hKXkwQvNp5DcZOcGebmP1qkGwbR8XjgxrfIDuJ1n6IVbqgrvtmqaRZ3U2L1dIGO/bIynL5Aw)

Uses the regparm(1) calling convention – argument in EAX, result in EAX.

Assembly:

```
.global f
f:
    dec eax
    xor eax, 1
    jz skip
    inc eax
skip:
    xor al, 1
    ret
```

[image: Graph of how this affects numbers]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
®¹m·αD_+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LpDO3MPbT@30SVe@/9/QwMA)

Exactly what Dennis's stuff does.

```
É4*+ÍD_+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cKeJlvbhXpd47f//DQ0A)

orlp's stuff.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 22 bytes

```java
r->r%2>0?r<2?2:r-2:r+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY49T8NADIbnu1/hBSkVzalkg4R0Q2Jg6ogYruklckh8J8epVKH@9mAgXRgsv3798bj3Z5/HFKg/fS44psgCvXpuFhxcO1MjGMm9rKK0Ns3HARtoBj9N8OaR7Jc1qzmJF03niCcYtZUdhJG69w/w3E0ba3TUtJEhQxJAeIbHUlMFD7vytzxiHxrJcKOzxhwuk4TRxVlc0jsykHZKa67W/Ef@3Lstq6SVdfu7eiUJXeAtrKKGVnEL5zXfFfVuz1WxL54417gvFmUYDjIzQet8SsMloz/w1S7f)

I wish Java had a `**` exponentiation operator. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 6 bytes

```
uedε1⟇
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=ued%CE%B51%E2%9F%87&inputs=&header=%40chain%3A1%7C&footer=%3B%0A1%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A2%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A3%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A4%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A5%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A6%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A7%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A8%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A9%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A10%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A11%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A12%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A13%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A14%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A15%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A16%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A17%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A18%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A19%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C%0A20%3A%E2%82%B4%20%60%5Ct-%3E%5Ct%60%E2%82%B4%20%40chain%3B%2C)

@Dennis' answer, ported directly to Vyxal. Requires the `r` flag to reverse the arguments, e.g. `ab+` evaluates to `b+a` instead of `a+b`.

Explanation taken from Dennis:

```
        # Implicit input -> n

ue      # Compute (-1)**n, yielding 1 for even n and -1 for odd n.
  d     # Unhalve; multipliy the result by 2.
   ε    # Compute the absolute difference of the result and n.
    1⟇  # If the difference is 0, yield 1.

        # Implicit output
```

Comment: Very clever use of the `r` flag. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
a@1=2;a@b_:=b+2(-1)^b
```

Move along, nothing to see here...