# Two interwoven chains

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

In [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135127/56656) question I defined a "chain" function as a function that:

- is a permutation, meaning that every value maps to and is mapped to by exactly one value.
- and allows any value can be obtained from any other value by repeated applications of the function or its inverse.

There are a lot of functions that do this and some of them are pretty simple (see the answers on that question).  Now we are going to define a separate class of functions I am going to call "interwoven" functions.  An interwoven function is a function on a set **A**, that has two infinite partitions **a<sub>0</sub>** and **a<sub>1</sub>** such that the function is a chain function on both **a<sub>0</sub>** and **a<sub>1</sub>**.

This means that no value in **a<sub>0</sub>** can map to a value in **a<sub>1</sub>** under the function or vice versa.

## Task

Your task is to write a code that performs or defines an interwoven function on the positive integers.  Your function can be anything as long as it satisfies the criteria for being interwoven.  You should include a explanation as to why your function is interwoven in the answer.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

Comment: I think this could be considered a dupe of the last challenge you linked, as you just have to make an additional transfromation, i.e. enumerating all the even and all the odd numbers seperately. I don't think any of the answers you're getting here will provide anything substantially new.

Comment: @flawr You could do that, but it wouldn't be the best way.  I've done a little experimentation with this and there are some novel ways to perform these types of functions.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 37 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to @notjagan*

```python
lambda x:1<x<4and x*2%5or x-(x&2)*4+4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nYwxEoIwEEX7nOI3Sha1IIQGiSexiROimZGFyVCsp4@oN7B9//23vNbHzG2JcLiWp59uwUP6ZpDBeg6Q2uy6OUNOWvaGanuwRTbXGBU3nJAY2fN91E1HPZaceNVyxMjBVXAXVHTG5xC1kPrNpL6F9o9CeQM)

Iterates the even and odd numbers with steps of 4 and links on 2 and 3:

```python
=> 22 => 18 => 14 => 10 => 6 => 2 => 4 => 8 => 12 => 16 => 20 => 24 =>
=> 23 => 19 => 15 => 11 => 7 => 3 => 1 => 5 => 9 => 13 => 17 => 21 =>
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 11 bytes

```
48 34 02 40 40 34 02 48 7E FA C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZE9b8MgEIZn8yuurqJA7FT5kDokcZbMXTpVaiqLYGxTYWxh3BJF@et1sRM3bRlAPPfevcfBqmqaMda290Ix2SQcNrVJRPmQb9EfJMXhP9NCZR1D3BquFfg7H05xTI2LHBrD4xhjzbOK6gLPCSEglIEUdzsl6zOidQEYnn2MHjJZHqiEFKUr5CWcAacWebbUQGUIC@Q5255pXnFqVjfwW/ST@C45XJTI09wg4gNZI9Q5F1SoSws6YyGwnGqYTNzlg6ATAre6oIUIZiEcu2Pd089cuKI4CCxsIpg/kp52q3JzMCn2RwKmWxiJvfJDsKF7qSXkkjxI9uqJslwoDqxM@Mq/hu3NJinhNKhhNFu8uFrHCONG1SJTPOkbnpCUvNogeHNTHBo7wp0rYnfLwbIxnRSP92p8RW4Sjfsm53RGbfvFUkmzup0Wy4Xb3GdEzpbLbw)

Uses the regparm(1) calling convention – argument in EAX, result in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:
    dec eax
    xor al, 2
    inc eax
repeat:
    inc eax
    xor al, 2
    dec eax
    jle repeat  # Jump back if pre-decrement value was ≤1
    ret
```

[image: Graph of how this affects numbers]

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```
a=>(a+=a&2?-4:4)<0?a*a:a
```

Sequences:

1. `... 19 15 11 7 3 1 5 9 13 17 21 ...`
2. `... 18 14 10 6 2 4 8 12 16 20 24 ...`

**Code snippet**

```js
f=a=>(a+=a&2?-4:4)<0?a*a:a
console.log('23 19 15 11 7 3 1 5 9 13 17'.split` `.map(a=>f(a|0)).join` `);
console.log('22 18 14 10 6 2 4 8 12 16 20'.split` `.map(a=>f(a|0)).join` `);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```apl
{x*1+0>x←4+⍵-8×2|⌊⍵÷2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqCi1DbQO7CiDTRPtR71Zdi8PTjWoe9XQB2Ye3G9UCVR1a8ah3s6mBAQA)

Same chains as my [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138145/65326).